# Shapes.Range(Array of ChartObjects) => Not possible to use array as input, even though the input shuld be an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way of selecting a range of ChartObjects based on "inconsistent" user-input, i.e. arrays of chart-names.

I thought that simply using the array as input would work, but unfortunately not. Could anyone help me? I could always manually change the input in the vba, but that is not very flexible nor robust...

`arrChrtObjcNames = Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")`

Do work:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")).Select`

`Selection.Group: Selection.Ungroup`

Do not work:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(arrChrtObjcNames).Select`

`Selection.Group: Selection.Ungroup`

Comment: It works. However, only if you use the variable that you filled with the names. With other words: You have a typo in the variable name (`Nams` instead of `Names`). And this is the reason you should **always** use **Option Explicit**.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. The typo is only here in my question. Not in my code. 
I changed names here to make it a bit more intuitive than my codes... 
Yet, the problem remains.

I will fix the question text though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to declare your variable correctly.

Either you don't have any declaration statement, or it is not correct. Assuming you have no declaration, VBA will create the variable on the fly as `Variant`. Now a `Variant` can be anything, including an array of anything. However, it seems that `Shapes.Range` doesn't like it if it is declared as `Variant`.

```
Dim arrChrtObjcNames As Variant
arrChrtObjcNames = Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(arrChrtObjcNames).Select  ' will fail
```

However, if you declare it as Array of Variant, it works:

```
Dim arrChrtObjcNames() As Variant
arrChrtObjcNames = Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(arrChrtObjcNames).Select  ' works
```

(why one works and the other not is beyond me)

Comment: Thank you. That was the correct solution. 
I have experienced thatt arrays can be quite tricky. But they have a lot of advantages too :) Again, thank you so much, and have a good day!